# can not get a kitty from crptokitties contract with id

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

when i am calling the getKitty function with a random id that I got from website, it is giving me an error. this is the code:

```
interface KittyInterface{
  function getKitty(uint256 _id)
        external
        view
        returns (
        bool isGestating,
        bool isReady,
        uint256 cooldownIndex,
        uint256 nextActionAt,
        uint256 siringWithId,
        uint256 birthTime,
        uint256 matronId,
        uint256 sireId,
        uint256 generation,
        uint256 genes
    );
}
```

```
address ckAddress = 0x06012c8cf97BEaD5deAe237070F9587f8E7A266d;
KittyInterface kittyContract = KittyInterface(ckAddress);
(,,,,,,,,,kittyDna) = kittyContract.getKitty(2010919);
```